# How do multiple hidden layers in a neural network improve its ability to learn?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

Most neural networks bring high accuracy with only one hidden layer, so what is the purpose of multiple hidden layers?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To answer you question you first need to find the reason behind why the term 'deep learning' was coined almost a decade ago. Deep learning is nothing but a neural network with several hidden layers. The term deep roughly refers to the way our brain passes the sensory inputs (specially eyes and vision cortex) through different layers of neurons to do inference. However, until about a decade ago researchers were not able to train neural networks with more than 1 or two hidden layers due to different issues arising such as [vanishing, exploding gradients](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vanishing_gradient_problem), getting stuck in local minima, and less effective optimization techniques (compared to what is being used nowadays) and some other issues. In 2006 and 2007 several researchers [1](http://www.cs.toronto.edu/~hinton/absps/fastnc.pdf) and [2](http://machinelearning.wustl.edu/mlpapers/paper_files/NIPS2006_739.pdf) showed some new techniques enabling a better training of neural networks with more hidden layers and then since then the era of *deep learning* has started.

In deep neural networks the goal is to mimic what the brain does (hopefully). Before describing more, I may point out that from an abstract point of view the problem in any learning algorithm is to approximate a function given some inputs **X** and outputs **Y**. This is also the case in neural network and it has been theoretically proven that a neural network with only **one hidden layer** using a bounded, continuous activation function as its units can approximate **any** function. The theorem is coined as **[universal approximation theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_approximation_theorem)**. However, this raises the question of **why** current neural networks with one hidden layer **cannot** approximate any function with a very very high accuracy (say >99%)? This could potentially be due to many reasons:

> - The current learning algorithms are not as effective as they should be
> - For a specific problem, how one should choose the exact number of hidden units so that the desired function is learned and the underlying manifold is approximated well?
> - The number of training examples could be exponential in the number of hidden units. So, how many training examples one should train a model with? This could turn into a chicken-egg problem!
> - What is the right bounded, continuous activation function and does the universal approximation theorem is generalizable to any other activation function rather than *sigmoid*?
> - There are also other questions that need to be answered as well but I think the most important ones are the ones I mentioned.

Before one can come up with provable answers to the above questions (either theoretically or empirically), researchers started using more than one hidden layers with limited number of hidden units. Empirically this has shown a great advantage. Although adding more hidden layers increases the computational costs, but it has been empirically proven that more hidden layers learn hierarchical representations of the input data and can better generalize to unseen data as well. By looking at the pictures below you can see how a *deep neural network* can learn hierarchies of features and combine them successively as we go from the first hidden layer to the one in the end:

[image]
Image taken from [here](http://www.slideshare.net/akshaymuroor/deep-learning-24650492)

As you can see, the first hidden layer (shown in the bottom) learns some edges, then combining those seemingly, useless representations turn into some parts of the objects and then combining those parts will yield things like faces, cars, elephants, chairs and ... . Note that these results were not achievable if new optimization techniques and new activation functions were not used.